# How to remove the view that I have created?

Tags: android

[image]Good day! I have used this line "ImageView iv = new ImageView(this)" to create an imageview in java however after creating I want to delete it with a button, how do I do that?

My goal was when I touch the screen the image will just follow the touched event.

Here's my code:

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    float pointX = event.getX();
    float pointY = event.getY();
     x = (int) event.getX();
     y = (int) event.getY();

    RelativeLayout re = (RelativeLayout)((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.re);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this.context);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.aw);
    ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(this.context);
    iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.aw);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80,80);
    params.topMargin=y;
    params.leftMargin=x;

    // Checks for the event that occurs
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
            if(flag ==0) {
                re.removeView(iv2);
                re.addView(iv, params);
                flag = 1;
            }
            if(flag == 1)
            {
                re.removeView(iv);
                re.addView(iv2, params);
                flag = 0;
            }
            if(c==1) {
                Context wdd = getContext();
                Intent i = new Intent(wdd, MainActivity.class);
                wdd.startActivity(i);
            }
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(flag ==0) {
                re.removeView(iv2);
                re.addView(iv, params);
                flag = 1;
            }
            if(flag == 1)
            {
                re.removeView(iv);
                re.addView(iv2, params);
                flag = 0;
            }
            path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
break;
 postInvalidate();
return true;
}
```

Comment: Use addView() to add, removeView() to remove

Comment: Use `parent_view_of_ iv.removeView(iv);`
`

Answer (score 1):

By remove if you mean **hide** the ImageView, based on a particular condition, do something like this:

```
if (your_condition) {
your_image_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 } else {
your_image_view.setVisibility(View.VISISBLE);
}
```

If you need to remove the image currently set to the **ImageView**, do this in the **if ... else** above (based on the condition)

```
your_image_view.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

OR

```
your_image_view.setImageBitmap(null);
```

If you need to remove the **ImageView** completely, call this, in the **if....else**, on the ImageView's container:

```
container.removeView(your_image_view);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your parent layout (RelativeLayout,LinearLayout or whatever it is) of your ImageView to a ViewGroup. Then remove that ImageView from that ViewGroup. Try something like this:

```
ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.parent_of_your_image_view);
View yourImg = (View) findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);
container.removeView(yourImg);
```